# change Fullcalendar event parameter after render

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

After an event is created, it is save to the database and waits for a response as a unique id (itemId).

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent) {

        var title = projectName;
        var eventData;
        if (title) {
            eventData = {
                id: getId(),
                itemId: 0,
                projectId: projectId,
                color: projectColor,
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: 0
            };
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
            //******** create event time

            $.ajax({
               url: 'index.php?call=saveItem',
               data: {title: eventData.title, start: start.format(), end: end.format(), pid: eventData.projectId, allDay: eventData.allDay},
               type: "POST",
               success: function(data) {
                    console.log('Added Successfully: '+data);
                    eventData.itemId = parseInt(data);
               },
               fail: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   console.log('error: '+jqXHR+":"+textStatus+":"+errorThrown);
               }

           });

        }
```

I have the itemId returned on 'success' but how do I now update itemId in the event to some number that I got back from the server instead of '0'?

I can render the event after the response is successful but since ajax is async, it takes a moment until the event renders like so

```
success: function(data) {
                    console.log('Added Successfully: '+data);
                    eventData.itemId = parseInt(data);

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);


               }
```

Is there is a solution to the original issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have recall event load function once ajax response success.

```
success: function (response) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
},
```